# How to add types to a curried function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, currying

In the following snippet of code where I have declared a curried add method.

```js
const add = (a: number) => {
  return (b?: number) => {
    return (b === undefined ? a : add(a + b))
  }
}
```

This works fine if I call this with the following arguments:
`add(1)()`

But typescript throws the following error when I call it like this:
`add(1)(2)()`

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'number | ((b?: number) => number | ...)' has no compatible call signatures.
```

What do I need to add to enable typed usage of this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would describe the type of `add()` as the following `Add` type:

```
type Add = (a: number) => Add2;
type Add2 = ((b: number) => Add2) & (() => number);
```

The `Add` function type takes a number and returns an `Add2`.

The `Add2` function type is an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function which returns a different type depending on the number and type of arguments that come in.  It's also self-referential: if you call an `Add2` with a `number` parameter, you get an `Add2` out.

You more or less need to use [assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that your `add()` is a valid `Add`:

```
const add = ((a: number) => (b?: number) =>
  b === undefined ? a : add(a + b)) as Add;
```

And then you should be able to use it as expected:

```
const x = add(1)(2)(3)(); // number
console.log(x); // 6
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKAKAhgLigOwK4C2ARhAE4CUyAfLAgEwDcAUKJLXHcmqkdvsWUpIa8DpQBk3ITX4kKzJgGMA9jgDOwKOgRdUGPoTnS0RAPwGBFakyhQiyJCjw44EAGYBLHBESmtUbG04DCgAajtySnQ1dgUVdU0ADy4g1ABGclQ6TIBmTPIGKAB6ItxDMiVVNWUAGwgAOhrlAHNURILi0oA2JiA)

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!